# Object keys not displaying anything in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have these (from what i can see) almost identical ways of doing what i want, yet the object.keys way is not displaying anything in my browser.

first way:

```
{this.state.months.map((month, index) => {
  for (var key in month) {
    if (month.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      return <div key={index} className="match">
            <input className="toggle" type="checkbox" />
            <label htmlFor="toggle">{month[key].month}</label>
            <div className="expand">
              {month[key].p1.name} {month[key].p1.score} {month[key].p2.name} {month[key].p2.score}
            </div>
          </div>
    }
  }
})}
```

second way:

```
{this.state.months.map((month, index) => {
  for (var key in month) {
    Object.keys(month).forEach((mnth)=>{
      console.log(month, 'm1');
      console.log(mnth, 'm2');
      return <div key={index} className="match">
        <input className="toggle" type="checkbox" />
        <label htmlFor="toggle">{month[mnth].month}</label>
        <div className="expand">
          {month[mnth].p1.name} {month[mnth].p1.score} {month[mnth].p2.name} {month[mnth].p2.score}
        </div>
      </div>
    })
  }
})}
```

the reason i want to use object.keys is because it is allowing me to iterate through multiple object properties. the first way was only showing the first key in each object

when i console.log (`month[mnth]`) I get exactly what i want. 
there are also no errors in the server console or the browser console. any ideas why it wont render? im changing nothing else and consistently doesn't render anything

Comment: forEach doesn't return anything, use map() or push to an outside var

Comment: First of all, the `key` property has to be unique per element in a map, so you could try something like `<div key={index + key}...` That might be why the first method shows only one key per object.

Comment: You also don't need two loops in the second method - either use `for (var key in month)` or `Object.keys(month).forEach()`. Not both.

Comment: @dandavis tried both of those and still had nothing rendered ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just use template ES6 string. Wrap your print elements like this

```
`${month[mnth].p1.name}` `${month[mnth].p1.score} ` `${month[mnth].p2.name} ` `${month[mnth].p2.score}`
```

You also need to return your elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the outer for loop and just use map in iterating thru the keys.

```
{this.state.months.map((month, index) => {
  Object.keys(month).map((mnth, mnthIndex)=>{
    console.log(month, 'm1');
    console.log(mnth, 'm2');
    return (<div key={`${index}-${mnthIndex}`} className="match">
      <input className="toggle" type="checkbox" />
      <label htmlFor="toggle">{month[mnth].month}</label>
      <div className="expand">
        {`${month[mnth].p1.name} ${month[mnth].p1.score} ${month[mnth].p2.name} ${month[mnth].p2.score}`}
      </div>
    </div>)
  })
})}
```

also, observe the use of combination if indexes in the second iteration as key to avoid similar keys. this could also be the reason why there's nothing being rendered in the browser.

Comment: for some reason still nothing is being rendered in the browser?

Comment: Hmm. I did a minor update on the code above. Could you try that?